# Names that sound similar to 99 Names of Allah

Tags: halal-haram

I know certain names of Allah are not allowed to be used to name your child. However, what about something like Musair (sounds similar to Al-Mussawir). Is something like this allowed?

Answer (score 0):

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته
Allahﷻ bless you
Yes It's is Permissible/halal